# how to write a query where the result of 2 queries are from the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

```
SELECT a_created_by,
         audited_type,
         a_created_date,
         audited_id,
         audited_name,
         event,
         i_org_id,
         string_2 AS user_added,
         string_3 AS user_id,
         username AS performer_id
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (string_3 IN ('bo.ze', 'co.xe', 'fo.re', 'ca.pe'))
        AND audited_type = 'abc_group'
        AND (event LIKE 'Added to Group%'
        OR event LIKE 'Removed from Group%')
        AND string_2 NOT LIKE 'TMF%'



SELECT a_created_by,
        audited_type,
       a_created_date,
       audited_id,
       audited_name,
       event,
       i_org_id,
       string_2 AS user_added,
        string_3 AS user_id,
        username AS performer_id
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (audited_name in ('Unblinded', 'Big Unblinded')
       AND audited_type = 'abc_group'
       AND (event LIKE 'Added to Group%'
       OR event LIKE 'Removed from Group%')
       AND string_2 NOT LIKE 'TMF%' )
```

Comment: You just pop both of those in a subquery and join them. Will look like `SELECT * FROM (<put query 1 here>) as query1 INNER JOIN (<put query 2 here>) as query2 ON query1.user_id = query2.user_id;`

Comment: Hi @JNevill, thank you for the answer. Do I need to put .something just like this? select cust.customer_id,
      cust.firstname,
      cust.lastname,
      cust.birthdate,
      cust.spouse_id,
      spouse.firstname as spouse_firstname,
      spouse.lastname as spouse_lastname
from customer cust
join customer spouse
on cust.spouse_id = spouse.customer_id;     || Example like a.a_created_by?

Comment: That's close. I will add as an answer so you can see the full code instead of the psuedocode.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a SELECT statement inside of parentheses to treat its result set as a "derived table" which can then be joined to other views, tables, or derived tables in the same statement. These are called "Subqueries". In your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (
      SELECT a_created_by,
         audited_type,
         a_created_date,
         audited_id,
         audited_name,
         event,
         i_org_id,
         string_2 AS user_added,
         string_3 AS user_id,
         username AS performer_id
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE (string_3 IN ('bo.ze', 'co.xe', 'fo.re', 'ca.pe'))
        AND audited_type = 'abc_group'
        AND (event LIKE 'Added to Group%'
        OR event LIKE 'Removed from Group%')
        AND string_2 NOT LIKE 'TMF%'
   ) as query1 /* "query1" is the alias for this derived table/subquery */
   INNER JOIN 
   (
     SELECT a_created_by,
        audited_type,
       a_created_date,
       audited_id,
       audited_name,
       event,
       i_org_id,
       string_2 AS user_added,
        string_3 AS user_id,
        username AS performer_id
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE (audited_name in ('Unblinded', 'Big Unblinded')
       AND audited_type = 'abc_group'
       AND (event LIKE 'Added to Group%'
       OR event LIKE 'Removed from Group%')
       AND string_2 NOT LIKE 'TMF%' )
    ) as query2
    ON query1.user_id = query2.user_id;
```

You can also use another syntax called Common Table Expressions to help keep your code clean. With a CTE you put your SQL for the derived table first. And then your final SELECT statement at the end that references the CTE derived tables by name (as if they were actual tables).

```
WITH query1 AS
(
     SELECT a_created_by,
         audited_type,
         a_created_date,
         audited_id,
         audited_name,
         event,
         i_org_id,
         string_2 AS user_added,
         string_3 AS user_id,
         username AS performer_id
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE (string_3 IN ('bo.ze', 'co.xe', 'fo.re', 'ca.pe'))
        AND audited_type = 'abc_group'
        AND (event LIKE 'Added to Group%'
        OR event LIKE 'Removed from Group%')
        AND string_2 NOT LIKE 'TMF%'
)
, query2 AS
(
     SELECT a_created_by,
        audited_type,
       a_created_date,
       audited_id,
       audited_name,
       event,
       i_org_id,
       string_2 AS user_added,
        string_3 AS user_id,
        username AS performer_id
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE (audited_name in ('Unblinded', 'Big Unblinded')
       AND audited_type = 'abc_group'
       AND (event LIKE 'Added to Group%'
       OR event LIKE 'Removed from Group%')
       AND string_2 NOT LIKE 'TMF%' )
)
SELECT * FROM query1 INNER JOIN query2 ON query1.user_id = query2.user_id;
```

These two queries are identical to eachother, just with different syntax. You may find that defining your subqueries/derived-tables as a CTE makes more sense and are easier to work with.